# grep on Windows XP vs. Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, grep, gnuwin32

I am using grep from [Gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) on Windows.

On **Windows XP**, the following

```
grep -e "foo" NUL
```

results in the following output

```
grep: NUL: invalid argument
```

On **Windows 7**, the same arguments result in no output at all.

grep just exits without any error message.

Why is the output different between Windows XP and Windows 7?

Comment: do grep -v just to see if the versions are the same

Comment: i'm on windows xp   C:\vin>grep --v  shows GNU grep 2.5.4  And I get no output when doing C:\vin>grep -e "foo" NUL

Answer (score 2):

**NUL** is the batch keyword for the null device (like /dev/null in linux) It is possible that in the second case, grep is correctly treating it as input, whereas in the first it is trying to access a file called 'NUL' (although this would not be the desired behavour since a file called 'NUL' cannot be created)